# The file /usr/libexec/mysqld does not exist or is not executable

Tags: centos, mysql, daemon

Whenever I try to start MySQL via the command

```
service mysqld start
```

I get the following error:

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

And looking into the logs I see this:

```
150706 14:52:12 mysqld_safe The file /usr/libexec/mysqld
does not exist or is not executable. Please cd to the mysql installation
directory and restart this script from there as follows:
./bin/mysqld_safe&
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/mysqld-safe.html for more information
```

Whenever I cd to /usr/ and run the command I get the same error:

```
[root@www usr]# ./bin/mysqld_safe
150707 10:15:19 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
150707 10:15:19 mysqld_safe The file /usr/libexec/mysqld
does not exist or is not executable. Please cd to the mysql installation
directory and restart this script from there as follows:
./bin/mysqld_safe&
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/mysqld-safe.html for more information
```

I am on CentOS version 6.6. How to get MySQL started?

Comment: what says `ls -al /usr/libexec/mysqld` ? Does this file exists?

Comment: Nope, there is no such file or directory, does this mean that i have to reinstall Mysql via yum?

Comment: you can check if it is installed: `rpm -qi mysql-server`, and you can install or reinstall: `yum (re)install mysql-server`.

Comment: @taliezin you should put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Huygens it was just a good catch, I didn't know what real problem was.

Comment: @taliezin ho, I was just advising you to put your comment as an answer (copy/paste it) so that the author of the question could accept your answer. It would help other people coming to this question in the future to quickly spot the answer :-)

Comment: @Huygens done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `CentOS 6.6` you can check if `mysql-server` is installed with:

```
rpm -qi mysql-server
```

And you can install it with:

```
yum install mysql-server
```

or reinstall it:

```
yum reinstall mysql-server
```